# How do you pull up the entire attribute table in Esri Collector app

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-collector

I am new to the Esri Collector app. How do I pull up the attribute table using the Esri Collector app on a tablet? I have searched everywhere on line and Esri but can't seem to find a simple answer to the question.

Comment: you dont,  you need a web app for that. or you can load the web map directly instead of using collector and get to the tables that way.

Comment: Have you published the data and is it accessible on the Collector already?

Comment: I have. I have also contacted esri support and they have indicated that this is not a feature as of yet in the mobile version of esri collector.